# why OutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs checks that output dir does not already exist

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Recently I am reading hadoop source code, when I read [OutputFormat](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/OutputFormat.java#L48) class, and `checkOutputSpecs` method has documentation like this:

```
Check for validity of the output-specification for the job.

<p>This is to validate the output specification for the job when it is
a job is submitted.  Typically checks that it does not already exist,
throwing an exception when it already exists, so that output is not
overwritten.</p>
```

My question is why output dir should not exist ?

My guess is that it can avoid overwriting old files in case of there is some `part-****` in output dir.

Is there any other reasons ?

Comment: You answered your question yourself.

Comment: @gudok  there is no more reasons why output dir should not exist ?  I don't think that it is a good design, and I think it is the programmer instead of the mapreduce framework  that should make sure output dir is safe to write .